# Send ~HI command to Zebra printer and receive the response in javascript clientside

Tags: javascript, printing, response, zebra-printers

I'm facing an issue and I cannot find a way to overcome it. If I send a ZPL command to print a label via XMLHttpRequest() like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var method = "POST";
var async = true;
var zpl = "^XA...^XZ";
var urlForPrint = "http://192.168.0.242/printer/pstprnt";
var urlForHi = "http://192.168.0.242:9100";
request.onload = function () {
    var status = request.status; // HTTP response status, e.g., 200 for "200 OK"
    var data = request.responseText; // Returned data, e.g., an HTML document.
}

request.open(method, urlForPrint, async);
request.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=unicode');
request.send(zpl);
```

it all works fine (prints the label). But before trying to print anything, I need to send the command ~HI, which, according to the documentation, should return a string with a number of properties, related to the printer at this IP.

**The problem:** I cannot receive this string.

```
var requestForPrinter = new XMLHttpRequest();
requestForPrinter.onerror = function (e) {
    //...
}
requestForPrinter.onload = function (e) {
    // I suppose that response message should arrive here, as a parameter of e
    //...
}

requestForPrinter.open(method, urlForHi, async);
requestForPrinter.send("~HI");
```

If I use PuTTY, the printer returns the message and it is displayed in the PuTTY console.
After a lot of research, I realized that PuTTY communicates with the printer via TCP/IP, while I'm trying to communicate with it via HTTP. So I have now got a clear idea what is the problem. But how to solve it?
A colleague of mine suggested creating a socket. So I tried [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), [TCPSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/API/TPC_Socket_API), [socket.IO](http://socket.io/docs/#using-it-just-as-a-cross-browser-websocket) with no success. Also, they seem not to be supported by all popular browsers and I couldn't manage to test them because of errors, which appeared in the browser's console. Tried to fix them with no luck.
Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

edit: I found [this](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket). So my second question is: I am just starting to learn node.js and find out its capabilites. I read somewhere, that It is a server-side js library. Can I use it only client-side? I mean, they have to be able to print labels using the printer in their LAN and to be able to work even if the Internet connection drops (to ask the server for data only once, at the beginning, when it loads some data into a JqGrid). So communicating with a server is not an option here.